# Cannot create property 'fillColor' on string ''

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I using google maps to draw polygon and has function to add Polygon object

Here is listener to polygon

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
  drawingControlOptions: {
    drawingModes: [
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
      google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON

    ]
  }
});

drawingManager.addListener('polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {

  currentShape = addPolygonPlace('unsaved', polygon.getPath().getArray(), '');
  polygon.setMap(null);
  drawingManager.setMap();
});
```

And here is function to adding Polygon.

```
function addPolygonPlace(id, paths, colors) {

  var place = new Polygon(id, paths, colors);
  mapWrapper.addPlace(place);

  place.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    placeInfobox.update(place);
    placeInfobox.show();
  });

  place.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    placeInfobox.hide();
  });

  place.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setEditable(false);
      google.maps.event.trigger(selectedShape, 'edit_end');
    }

    place.setEditable(true);
    selectedShape = place;
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(place, 'edit_end', function() {
    if (place.id === 'unsaved') {
      return;
    }
    var placeToEdit = getPlaceByDescription(place.id);
    var path = place.googleEntity.getPath().getArray();

    updatePlace(place.id);
  });

  return place;
}
```

Also as you can see from this row `var place = new Polygon(id, paths, colors);`

I have using Polygon object with properties , here is it's code.

```
var Polygon = (function() {

  'use strict';

  function Polygon(id, paths, colors) {

    this._visible = true;
    this.id = id;
    this.paths = paths;
    // this.infoboxDescription = infoboxDescription;

    if (colors === undefined || colors === null) {
      colors = {
        fillColor: '#006400',
        strokeColor: '#646464'
      };
    }

    if (colors.fillColor === undefined || colors.fillColor === null) {
      colors.fillColor = '#006400';
    }

    if (colors.strokeColor === undefined || colors.strokeColor === null) {
      colors.strokeColor = '#646464';
    }

    this.googleEntity = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeColor: colors.strokeColor,
      fillColor: colors.fillColor,
      paths: paths
    });
  }

  Object.defineProperty(Polygon.prototype, 'visible', {
    get: function() {
      return this._visible || (this._visible = false);
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });

  Polygon.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.googleEntity.setMap(null);
  }

  Polygon.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, callback) {
    this.googleEntity.addListener(eventName, callback.bind(this));
  }

  Polygon.prototype.setEditable = function(editable) {
    this.googleEntity.setEditable(editable);
  }

  return Polygon
})()
```

But I have error. In this row

if (colors.fillColor === undefined || colors.fillColor === null) {
       colors.fillColor = '#006400';
   }

I have this one

> Cannot create property 'fillColor' on string ''
>       at new Polygon (Place.js:65)
>       at addPolygonPlace (Index.js:1895)

How I can solve it?

Comment: is not fillcolor a field of the Polygon? shouldn't be something like place.fillColor  instead of colors.fillColor?

Comment: In the first snippet, you're calling `addPolygonPlace` with a string as the `colors` parameter, which means it is neither `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @KevinDrost no, it's an empty string.

Comment: @MrUpsidown An empty string is still a string. So it won't be an Object

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But it won't be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Ah... sorry I read your "neither" as "either"! Got your point. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"use strict";

var colors = 'string';
colors.fillColor = 'abc';
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'fillColor' on string 'string'

```
"use strict";

var colors = {};
colors.fillColor = 'abc';
```

> No error

If this needs any comment: you can't create an [object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on a variable of type `string`.

Comment: `currentShape = addPolygonPlace('unsaved', polygon.getPath().getArray(), '');` here you are passing `colors` to your `addPolygonPlace` as an empty string (the 3rd argument).

Comment: Thank's, that helps!